# java 8 nested streams

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Suppose you have structure classes like this:

```
public class Review{
    private Integer idReview;
    private String description;
    private ArrayList<RelReviewImage> images;
}

public class RelReviewImage{
    private Integer idRelReviewImage;
    private Integer idImage;
    private String name;
}
```

With Java 8 and `Stream`s we want to do a filter for `idImage` and return `Review` objects.
Is it possible? One level is easy, but 2 levels we can't find any example or documentation.

Comment: Your question is unclear - can you show an example of code with an input and the expected output?

Answer (score 23):

Guess what you need: (Assume getters are available for `Review` and `RelReviewImage`)

```
List<Review> originalReviews = ...

List<Review> result = originalReviews.stream()
    .filter(review -> review.getImages().stream() //Nested streams. Assume getImages() never null, but empty 
                          .anyMatch(image -> image.getIdImage() == 123)) //'2 level' here
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you can get the most maintainable and elegant code here by not trying for a one-liner. :)

When I have these nested structures, I usually **create a new method for each level**. So that when I'm coding, I only have to have one level in my head at a time.

Try pulling the part that checks if there exists an image with `imageId` into a `Predicate`.

A `Predicate` here is a `Function` that takes your `Review` and returns a `Boolean` that can be filtered on.

```
public List<Review> filterReviews(){
    Integer idImage = 1;
    List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    List<Review> result = reviews.stream()
            .filter(hasImage(idImage))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return result;
}

private Predicate<Review> hasImage(final Integer idImage){
    return review -> review.images.stream()
            .anyMatch(image -> Objects.equals(image.idImage, idImage));
}
```

*Protip*

If the `filterReviews`-method had taken the `Predicate` as a parameter, you can use the same method, to filter on all different fields inside `Review`, by passing different `Predicates`.

Comment: To my opinion it's much better to add a `hasImage` method to the `Review` class which just returns plain old `boolean`. Then you can `.filter(Review::hasImage)`. This would also encapsulate the `images` storage. Suppose that later you will change `List<RelReviewImage> images` to `Map<Integer, RelReviewImage> id2image`. Then `hasImage` will be reduced to `return id2image.containsKey(idImage);`

Answer (score -1):

Here is some basic Idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        List<RelReviewImage> revImg = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            revImg.add(new RelReviewImage(j, j, "img_"+j));
        }
        reviews.add(new Review(i, "rev" + i, revImg));
    }

    List<Review> result = reviews.stream().filter(r -> r.getImages().stream().anyMatch(i -> i.getIdImage().intValue() < 2)).collect(Collectors.toList());

}

public class Review {
    private Integer idReview;
    private String description;
    private List<RelReviewImage> images;

    public Review(Integer id, String desc, List<RelReviewImage> img) {
        super();
        this.idReview = id;
        this.description = desc;
        this.images = img;
    }

    public Integer getIdReview() {
        return idReview;
    }

    public void setIdReview(Integer idReview) {
        this.idReview = idReview;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<RelReviewImage> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<RelReviewImage> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
}

public class RelReviewImage {
    private Integer idRelReviewImage;
    private Integer idImage;
    private String name;

    public RelReviewImage(Integer id, Integer id_img, String name) {
        super();
        this.idRelReviewImage = id;
        this.idImage = id_img;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getIdRelReviewImage() {
        return idRelReviewImage;
    }

    public void setIdRelReviewImage(Integer idRelReviewImage) {
        this.idRelReviewImage = idRelReviewImage;
    }

    public Integer getIdImage() {
        return idImage;
    }

    public void setIdImage(Integer idImage) {
        this.idImage = idImage;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

The requirement says you want to filter based on idImage which is the field in our stream of list ArrayList images
Step1:

```
images.stream()
    .filter(idImage->idImage.equals("I123");
```

Our aim will be satisfied if any match is found so

Step2:

```
images.stream()
        .filter(idImage->idImage.equals("I123")
        .findAny()//this will return Optional<RelReviewImage> object which will be populated if object is found also need not worry about null condition
        .isPresent()//this will check if the Optional<RelReviewImage> object was populated
```

But from where do we get this images stream?
It is present in Review class so one can directly say 
Step 3

```
Review myReview-new Review();
            myReview.getImages.stream()
                            .filter(idImage->idImage.equals("I123")
                            .findAny()
                            .isPresent()
```

But we want to have all listOfReviewObjects
Assuming we have ListOfReviewObjects

```
//Ignore below line of code if not clear,bottomLine is you get list of review objects
            List<Review> reviews = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).mapToObj(e->new Review()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Step 4

```
reviews.stream()
            .filter("XYZ condition")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Our filter criteria is as per step 2 so collating each piece we have

Step 5

```
reviews.stream()
        .filter(review->review.getImages().stream()
                                            .filter(relReviewImage->relReviewImage.getIdImage().intValue()==imageId)
                                            .findAny()
                                            .isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code (by editing the answer) such that others can learn from it?

Comment: `.filter(predicate).findAyn().isPresent()` can be simplified to `anyMatch(predicate)` (your solution then becomes the same as others already provided)