# Java 8 nested streams : return a value in last stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This question can be considered as based on [java 8 nested streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234931/java-8-nested-streams)

Suppose I have a `Batch` with `Basket`s with `Item`s :

```
public class Batch {
    private List<Basket> baskets;
}

public class Basket {
    private List<Item> items; 
}

public class Item {
    private String property;
    private int value;
}
```

I would like to rewrite this method with Java 8 streams.

```
public class SomeService {
    public int findValueInBatch(Batch batch) {
        for (Basket basket : batch.getBaskets()) {
            for (Item item : basket.getItems()) {
                if (item.getProperty().equals("someValue") {
                    return item.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How should I do it ?

First step to where I'd like to go :

```
public int findValueInBatch(Batch batch) {
    for (Basket basket : batch.getBaskets()) {
        basket.getItems().stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getProperty.equals("someValue") 
            .findFirst()
            .get();
            // there I should 'break'
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your original method doesn't compile.

Comment: @shmosel true, I lack parentheses item.getProperty() and a return value if no element is found. The goal is to show the principle though. Fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
baskets.stream()
            .flatMap(basket -> basket.getItems().stream())
            .filter(item -> item.equals("someValue"))
            .findAny()
            .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

The advantage of using `findAny` instead of `findFirst` is that `findFirst` doesn't work with parallel streams. Therefore, if you want to parallelize the above operation all you'll need to do is replace the `stream()` method with `parallel()`

Comment: All answers are suitable, thanks to all. I choose this one for the findAny tip. Rather than throw an exception we can return an Optional and then test if the result isPresent().

Answer (score 5):

1. Use `flatMap` to get ride of nested lists, extract each `List<Item>` and merge them into a `Stream<Item>`, it acts like all substream were merged together.
2. Use `filter` to ignore the non matching elements.
3. Use `findFirst` to get the first occurence only and stop processing
4. Use `orElseThrow` to throw an exception if no occurence of **someValue** were found.

Here you go

```
public class SomeService {
    public int findValueInBatch(Batch batch) {
        return batch.getBaskets().stream()
            .flatMap(basket -> basket.getItems().stream())
            .filter(item -> item.getProperty.equals("someValue"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("value not found"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of flatMap, that really helped. A detail : IllegalArgumentException does not really fit here (not the core of the question).

Comment: No problem, i used it as a placeholder, but you can use the one that suits your need. Or even use `orElse(a default int value)` but i'd rather use orElseThrow if i were you

Answer (score 4):

To eliminate both loops you can use `flatMap` to produce a `Stream<Item>` of all the `Item`s of all the `Basket`s :

```
return batch.getBaskets()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(b -> b.getItems().stream())
            .filter(item -> item.getProperty.equals("someValue"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(some default value); // using .get() would throw an exception
                                         // if no match is found
```